# How to make Highstock work with two xAxis?

Tags: highcharts

The navigator in Highstock only seems to affect the first xAxis. The second xAxis, as in the example linked to below, isn't rescaled, and always shows all data.

```
See jsfiddle below:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wardrop/t9ug4pm7/7/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set extremes in the second axis manually after extremes are set in the first axis.

```
xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
    minRange: 24 * 3600000, // 1 day
    labels: {
      align: "left",
      rotation: 45
    },
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%e %b %Y'
    },
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
        this.chart.xAxis[1].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, true, false);
      }
    }
  },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ug4pm7/9/

You can also linked two axis, so the linked axis' extremes will follow after the master axis. But for columns it is needed to define pointRange because without it, columns might be drawn incorrectly.

```
, { //axis
      type: 'datetime',
      linkedTo: 0, // linked to master axis
      minRange: 24 * 3600000,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickWidth: 0,
      labels: {enabled: false},
      opposite: true
  }

series: [{
        id: 'daily',
        name: 'Daily',
        type: 'column',
        color: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
        data: data['daily'],
        pointRange: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
      },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ug4pm7/11/